# Assigning AutomationIds to a UWP ComboBox

Tags: testing, combobox, uwp, appium, uwp-xaml

I've seen some related WPF examples, but I'm having problems assigning automationIds to the items in a UWP ComboBox.
This example [XAML - Automation ID for ComboBox elements in DataGridComboBoxColumn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9398130/xaml-automation-id-for-combobox-elements-in-datagridcomboboxcolumn) uses EditingElementStyle, but I don't see intellisense autocomplete that in my XAML code.

```
<ComboBox x:Name="SampleComboBox" ItemsSource ="{Binding SampleList}" 
AutomationProperties.AutomationId="SampleReason" SelectionChanged="Sample_OnSelectionChanged"
Height="40" Width="120" FontSize="18"  BorderBrush="#cccccc" BorderThickness="1"  
Background="White" Margin="0 0 2 0"  VerticalAlignment="Bottom"></ComboBox>
```

Where the SampleList as the data source is defined in the viewmodel as

```
SampleList = null;
 string[] sampleTypes =
 {
      _screenText.GetString("SampleText1/Text"),
      _screenText.GetString("SampleText2/Text")
 };
 SampleList = new ObservableCollection<string>(sampleTypes);
```

Comment: Use the binding in the style does not work in UWP. Please post your code about using the `AutomationProperties.AutomationId`.

Comment: Um, there's no code to post?

Comment: There's this example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9113527/add-automation-id-to-bound-combo-box-items but the answer doesn't really appear to match up to the question asked. I don't have a model, just a list.